# document.cookie doesn't work for https://httpbin.org/cookies site in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, cookies

I am using `Firefox 73.0.1 (64-bit)`.

`document.cookie = "name=value"` can't add new cookie in Firefox for this site `https://httpbin.org/cookies` but Chrome does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1280377

> The https://httpbin.org/cookies file appears to be a JSON file
>   containing a cookies object. Firefox renders this page in a viewer
>   rather than in raw text form. You may need to disable the viewer first
>   before testing:
>
> (1) In a new tab, type or paste about:config in the address bar and
>   press Enter/Return. Click the button accepting the risk.
>
> (2) In the search box above the list, type or paste json and pause
>   while the list is filtered
>
> (3) Double-click the devtools.jsonview.enabled preference to switch
>   the value from true to false